# ClojureScript compiler NullPointerException on OS X when trying to compile simple project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I tried following the ClojureScript quick start guide http://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start and hit an NPE trying to manually invoke the clojurescript compiler on OS X.

I have java 1.8.0_92

```
% javac -version
javac 1.8.0_92
```

I made a new directory (for the sake of completeness ~/tmp/clojure/cljstest/). All paths are relative to this directory. I think I am using version 1.9.293 of clojurescript.

```
% cat $(which cljsc)
#!/bin/bash
exec java  -jar /usr/local/Cellar/clojurescript/1.9.293/libexec/cljs.jar "$@"
```

The `cljsc` jar by itself, however, works fine.

```
%  cljsc
Clojure 1.8.0
user=>
```

I also downloaded the standalone cljs.jar mentioned in the tutorial and checked the md5sum to make sure that they're the same.

```
% wget https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/releases/download/r1.9.293/cljs.jar
% md5 cljs.jar
MD5 (cljs.jar) = 658d7b722cebe46e36604baf9eecfcb5
% md5 /usr/local/Cellar/clojurescript/1.9.293/libexec/cljs.jar
MD5 (/usr/local/Cellar/clojurescript/1.9.293/libexec/cljs.jar) = 658d7b722cebe46e36604baf9eecfcb5
```

I ran

```
% mkdir -p src/hello_world
```

and then

```
% touch ./src/hello_world/core.cljs
```

The contents of ./src/hello_world/core.cljs are:

```
(ns hello-world.core)

(enable-console-print!)

(println "Hello World!")
```

The contents of ./build.clj are:

```
(require 'cljs.build.api)

(cljs.build.api/build "src" {:output-to "out/main.js"})
```

I downloaded clojure through homebrew

```
% where cljsc
/usr/local/bin/cljsc
```

This is a shell script that I used to locate the .jar

```
% cat $(which cljsc)
#!/bin/bash
exec java  -jar /usr/local/Cellar/clojurescript/1.9.293/libexec/cljs.jar "$@"
```

I tried running the compiler with the explicit classpath given in the tutorial

```
% java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/clojurescript/1.9.293/libexec/cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj
```

That produced the following stack trace:

```
 % java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/clojurescript/1.9.293/libexec/cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException,     compiling:(/Users/gregnisbet/tmp/clojure/cljstest/build.clj:3:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:335)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:330)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cljs.closure$build.invokeStatic(closure.clj:1920)
        at cljs.build.api$build.invokeStatic(api.clj:198)
        at cljs.build.api$build.invoke(api.clj:187)
        at cljs.build.api$build.invokeStatic(api.clj:190)
        at cljs.build.api$build.invoke(api.clj:187)
        at user$eval24.invokeStatic(build.clj:3)
        at user$eval24.invoke(build.clj:3)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        ... 11 more
```

I expected the clojurescript compiler to either produce `main.js` or give me a clojurescript-related error message. Why is the ClojureScript compiler throwing a NullPointerException? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using leiningen or boot? these tools could help you with setting up the projects...

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. Can you recheck that these are the exact steps that led to the exception? For this tutorial you really need only `java` and the stand-alone `cljs.jar`, so I am not sure why you mention 'downloading Clojure through homebrew'?

Comment: @AntonHarald. I was just trying to invoke the compiler using as few tools as possible. I don't have a good understanding of what exactly leiningen is automating, so I was trying this first.
glts, initially I thought this may have been an error with the homebrew formula, and I just wanted to confirm that it is the same binary as the standalone jar listed in the tutorial. I left the information about the homebrew in since there might be other people in my situation who tried installing the cljsc compiler through homebrew and are having problems getting started.